# Why not to add tor2web-like gateways to relays by default?

Tags: onion-services, relays

as it is said in this article
https://blog.torproject.org/facebook-hidden-services-and-https-certs

> whatever it is you think Tor is for, I guarantee there's a person out
>   there who uses it for something you haven't considered.

Users can navigate through normal internet by using Tor and also they can navigate through .onion pages.

There is a case which is not considered (mine).
I have a service in which users do not need to be anonymous at all, (though they can) because it is not required at any level ... but, indeed, it is required to hide the service, because competitors could take (dangerous) actions

I read people who think tor2web is not secure, OK!, it is not secure for users wanting security, but, if user level security is not required, relays could offer gateways services, don't you think ?

Then all use cases would be covered ...

If you know a network, other than tor, that gives this kind of service tell me, i would appreciate it

Regards

(Sorry about my english)

Answer (score 0):

Tor relays do not directly serve or have the ability to see what they serve.

Adding this feature would likely cause legal problems for relay operators in many places.

It would also provide an increased attack surface for relays.